# I need cross browser code for window.clipboardData.setData

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I need a cross-browser for my code below, any assistance will be much appreciated.

```
<script>    
function generateTicketText() {
    var scmTicketText = "";
    scmTicketText = "Problem Statement: " + document.getElementById("probStatement").value + "\n\n";
    scmTicketText += "Root Cause: " + document.getElementById("rootCause").value + "\n\n";
    if (document.getElementById("probTicket").value !== "") {
        scmTicketText += "Problem Ticket: " + document.getElementById("probTicket").value + "\n\n";
    }
    scmTicketText += "Resolution: " + document.getElementById("Resolution").value + "\n\n";
    scmTicketText += "SCM Sub-Area: " + document.getElementById("hidSubArea").value + "\n\n";
    scmTicketText += "Sub-Category: " + document.getElementById("hidSubCat").value + "\n\n";
    scmTicketText += "Process Step: " + document.getElementById("hidStep").value;
    document.getElementById("scmText").value = scmTicketText;
    //set fail state of copy as default
    document.getElementById("btnGenerateCopy").style.color = "Red";
    document.getElementById("btnGenerateCopy").value = "Copy Failed";
    //copies output into clipboard and validates success
    if (window.clipboardData.setData('Text', scmTicketText)) {
        document.getElementById("btnGenerateCopy").style.color = "LimeGreen";
        document.getElementById("btnGenerateCopy").value = "Copied to Clipboard";
    }
}    
</script>
```

Comment: Hint: it's unlikely anyone will try to read code that isn't formatted. Hit the button with the < and > signs in it, then preview your question.

Comment: Thank you HeyHeyJC, hope this is better.